# pgAdmin4 got removed after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10

Tags: software-installation, 19.10, pgadmin

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10. After upgrade I noticed that pgAdmin4 got removed while other softwares are still present and now when I try to install pgadmin4 from the terminal, I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pgadmin4 : Depends: pgadmin4-common (= 4.18-1.pgdg18.04+1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have installed pgadmin3 but I really want pgadmin4. Is that possible?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was tested to upgrade to 18.10 (ie. the next release) and will be tested to upgrade to 20.04 LTS before 20.04.1 is released (in earnest; yes many people do tests outside of those but those are the ones where QA testing is recorded) and thus those are the only upgrade paths supported (without re-install).  Your 'upgrade' was neither officially tested, nor is officially supported.  (one LTS to the next LTS, or one release to the next).

Comment: I don't see `pgadmin4` is official repositories either - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=pgadmin4&searchon=names  (so providing your source may also have been helplful.  For best results with 3rd party software, you should remove then prior to *release-upgrade* & re-add them back after as QA-testing for release-upgrades uses official sources only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can understand the `pgadmin4` package was installed from third-party repository.

Quick search gives me this page - https://atalia.postgresql.org/morgue/p/pgadmin4/ .

So you have to open Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and enable line similar to above.

Or add this repository again as described in http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt:

```
sudo apt-get install curl ca-certificates gnupg lsb-release
curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin4
```